# dataListAdapter gives me an error when trying to create it - Android

Tags: android, class, baseadapter

I am trying to create a class that extends BaseAdapter but when I try to declare the class is gives me an error here is my code,

```
    l1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        l1.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new dataListAdapter(comments,numbers,usernames));


     class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
               //example

    }
```

When I place the code

```
    l1.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new dataListAdapter(comments,numbers,usernames));
```

dataListAdapter is underlined and says i need to create a class named dataListAdapter and I do? It's right underneath it?

Comment: Are you declaring dataListAdapter class inside the onCreate method? Post the full code of the activity please...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your dataListAdapter is a inner Static class - it should be positioned inside of the parent class (not inside a method). It needs to be static so it 'appears' as it's own class file, when really its inside another class file.

Also java naming conventions are that a class starts with an Upper case letter, so DataListAdapter :)